# configuring redis_host in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have purchased this laravel script and this is the configuration of my .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:p8u22GdWV3ltFAoVzHIUxqoEnlQBpliDzqt7f+pr+ME=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://mydomain

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=u532092539_smily
DB_USERNAME=u532092539_smily
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

What is redis_host here and what it does? Should I configure it or not? Please help.

Comment: Leave it as is, it's already configured although I doubt it was used in code. To check that search for `Redis` in `app` directory files' code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is an open source tool for advanced key-value store in memory.
if your project require then configure else remove default value from file.

Comment: I am having trouble configuring email settings in this Laravel project. Can you please help me with it?